# How to fix ui actionbar nativescript error

Tags: user-interface, nativescript

After new version of nativescript, My page is over lap menu. How to fix its

[image]

Comment: Which device / OS version you are testing it with. Are you able to reproduce the issue with Playground?

Comment: I use android 9 on testing and this code is starting code. I am not coding more than nativescript give

Comment: I start code with `tns create application --ts` and result is like image I show

Comment: Did you test with different device? What device brand & model you are using?

Comment: I test on Motorola Android 9, Huawei Android 6 and IPad and Result is show same image

Comment: I don't see the issue on my end. Are you sure you see same results in Playground too?

Comment: I test on Playground result is ok but on `tns run android`. result is over lap and only on android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix by app\App_Resources\Android\src\main\res\values-v21\style.xml

coding this on `<style name="AppThemeBase21" parent="AppThemeBase">`

`<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>`